# "Factory" which produces a "connection" object

Tags: c#, beginner, factory-method

I am a newbie in C# and in OOP in general. I decided to create a class that should give out a "connection" object. I would like your advice and critique on improving it.

```
public class Connection_Factory
{

  private string Last_Connection_Trying   = "";
  private string Last_Connection_Success = "";
  public OracleConnection Build(string connection_string)
  {
    Last_Connection_Trying = connection_string;
    return new OracleConnection(connection_string);
  }

  public OracleConnection Build()
  {
    return Build(Last_Connection_Success);
  }

  public void Mark_Connection_as_Successful(string connection_string)
  {
    Last_Connection_Success = connection_string;
  }

  public void Mark_Connection_as_Successful()
  {
    Last_Connection_Success = Last_Connection_Trying;
  }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of marking a connection as successful? This factory does not make any sense.

Comment: For example, user is trying to connect to Server via Login Form. If connection was successful then you mark connection as successful and futher you can create a connections without neccessity of repeated specifying a connection string again.

And in general I guess that creating a connection object should be in one point in application.

Comment: Do you have more then one connection string or why would you want to avoid specifying it multiple times or rather why should you need to specify it more then once? It's not like it changes all the time, is it?

Comment: yeah, I can have more than one database, let's say test DB and production DB.

Comment: so if you cannot connect to the production db successfuly you'd change the connection string to the test db?

Comment: And the other case: why we need every time specify the same connection string (during opening new connection) it's easier to remember last successful connection string and use it.

Comment: @GordonFreeman But the client code specifies the connection string the first time. So why shouldn't it be expected to continue to do so? And in fact the client either has to continue to supply a connection string when calling Build, or knowingly switch to the parameterless overload. This imo is too much knowledge of the factory's internals.

Comment: @eurotrash Imagine, that our application has many sub-forms (or child forms) using process of connection object creation. In your case each sub-form must know about content of connection string. Do you think is this ok?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your code lacks any comments saying what it does and why.  When I first looked at your post I assumed it was a TCP socket class and was looking for the port number.  Also the layout could be improved, regular blank lines, etc.

I would do this:

```
public void Mark_Connection_as_Successful()
{
    Mark_Connection_as_Successful(Last_Connection_Trying);
}
```

just like you have with Build.  At the moment they are trivial functions, but that might not always be the case.

Would it be appropriate to verify the format of the connection string, or is this done in the OracleConnection constructor?

Comment: Thank you, Matt, I agree with you.

And I think that verifying connection string format is a responsibility of OracleConnection constructor.

Comment: Comments should say why, not what... *the code* should say *what* all by itself ;-)

Comment: I never remember which one its meant to be, its not like I write any :)